# Class Validators are not working when the type is a Record <k,v> - NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typescript-typings, class-validator

We have a DTO property where its type is `Record<string, Animal>` and `Animal` is another DTO with class validators like @IsDefined(), @IsNotEmpty(). However these validations are not working as expected and it's probably because it has the Record type.

I already tried adding `@ValidatedNested({ each: true })` but still didn't work. How could we make the validation work for the `Animal` dto in `Record<string, Animal>`?

Comment: typescript world: types are erased at runtime, this is why you can't rely on `Record` type. I don't use `class-validator` so I can't help you.

Comment: Can you add your controller and dto (all your dtos) to your post?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**
You can try building partial class validator, https://trilon.io/blog/introducing-mapped-types-for-nestjs here is some documentation.
for e.g:

```html
export class Record extends PartialType(
  OmitType(Animal , ['legs'] as const),
) {}
```